# Licensing a font for a clients website use?

Tags: fonts, licensing

How does font licensing work for client web usage?  Currently I use typekit through Creative Cloud for fonts on my projects.  Every font foundry I see charges by the page view for web fonts.  If a client has a small business with under 500k views then suddenly blows up and is getting some ridiculous number of views how would that work?  Do I just eat the cost of buying them more views?  Also, what if a client decides to stop hosting their site with me and wants to go with another company?  Am I just supposed to say well you have to buy a typekit membership(or whatever foundry) and switch the linking to your account?

Comment: Just pointing out that *this very reason* is why I feel Typekit and all web-font subscription services are **severely** flawed from the start and one reason I will never fall for the subscription model of pricing.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to a non subscription foundry?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Typekit help](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/1341590-typekit-font-licensing), you're only allowed to serve fonts on your client's website if you are on a business plan, and page views of that plan start at 2M.
It also suggests that you could set up a Typekit account for each client, as you proposed.
Personally, I would go for the second option, avoiding to absorb a recurring cost that depends on customer actions.

I used to provide free hosting to my website design clients, all of them with very low page views. One day I realized it made no sense to assume the recurring cost myself for work made years ago in some cases, and started charging a fee for it. It became a little but stable source of income. Clients usually don't understand the different aspects and complexities of the service you are providing and are happy to pay you to take care of it.
It may work for your case as well, but I would check if it is legal in this particular scenario.